# Updating a relationship with a merge

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the `MERGE` functionality to create or update a node, and create a relationship between them as follows:

```
MATCH (p:Part{f:'fff'})
MERGE (m:Item {p1: {map}.p1})
ON CREATE SET m = {map}
ON MATCH SET m += {map}
MERGE (m)-[:USED_WITH{pri:'High'}]->(p)
```

However, when I re-run this, but change the property `pri` on a subsequent run, a new relationship is created. What I want is for the original relationship to be updated.

What's the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MERGE` ensures that the pattern exists exactly as described, including the properties and values, and creates a new one otherwise.

When you change the value of the property `pri` in the pattern, Cypher doesn't find a match for the pattern because the property value is different, so it creates a new relationship.

You can use `MERGE` on the relationship type,
then use `SET` to update the property value:

```
MERGE (m)-[r:USED_WITH]->(p)
SET r.pri = "Low"
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!